# Using Xstream for dynamic content

Tags: xstream

I am trying to deal with a special scenario with Xstream where the XML structure is not know in advance for part of xml.

I could successfully serialize/deserialize xml whose structure is known advance.

For eg:

```
<MemberList>

<Member id="1">
...
</Member>

<Member id="2">
...
</Member>

</MemberList>
```

But for below fragment, we don't know what all can come inside context element. And obvisouly, we could not let xstream, how to map elements inside this element.

```
<MemberList>

<!-- Structure not known for this element -->
<Context>
   <!-- can contain any arbitrary xml whose structure not known in advance -->
</Context>

<Member id="1">
...
</Member>

<Member id="2">
...
</Member>
```

How can I reproduce the exact xml back from deserialized object, with Context element and its contents exactly copied back in serialized xml.